# Python Boolean: any value of a list in another list or dictionary

Tags: python, boolean-expression

I just recently found myself writing this line of code, which i did not like too much:

```
if ('upload' in request.POST) or ('delete' in request.POST):
```

I allready thought about list comprehension, which would look like this:

```
if [value for value in ['upload','delete'] if value in request.POST]:
```

Which is not exactly better. My very simple question is: can this be simplified? Or is this just trying to be too smart?

Comment: I do think you're trying to be too smart. Still the exercise is interesting.

Comment: Which is exactly why i ask this question. I do, of course, use such lines as the upper one without getting a headache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write it more concisely by using set intersection:

```
if {'upload', 'delete'} & set(request.POST):
```

Or more explicitly:

```
if {'upload', 'delete'}.intersection(request.POST):
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplification uses `any()`.

```
if any(value for value in ['upload','delete'] if value in request.POST):
```